# Strange TWRP behaviour, please help!

Tags: adb, twrp, xiaomi

I switched from dotOS to Pixel Experience because I wanted to get a taste of A12. After the change my phone started behaving strangely. It doesn't turn up on Windows File Explorer anymore and ADB doesn't detect my phone unless I set it to USB charge only. Plus the biggest problem of them all- TWRP doesn't work anymore. Whenever I reboot my phone it boots into TWRP, and the screen keeps flashing at the TWRP logo. The only way to boot to A12 is to enter fastboot and hit fastboot continue in the CMD. I'm at my wits end here and honestly a bit desperate. I wiped my device completely before installing Pixel Experience and I think that may be the problem. I fear that I may have sort of permanently damaged my phone or something.

Device used is a POCO M2 Pro (resold as Redmi Note 9 pro in other markets).

Attached are the logs I pulled using ADB when the TWRP screen was flashing.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uVsCYFKQRYM7dP7_lG4xidhAQjfWZvtm/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your device has been released with Android 10. Please update to at least TWRP 3.5.0 for Android 10 support.